# Integration of Cosine with a Dot Product in Argument Over Symmetric Bounds

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

I am attempting to solve the following integration:

$$\int_{-N_D}^{N_D}\cdots\int_{-N_2}^{N_2}\int_{N_1}^{N_1} \cos\left(
  2\pi \left(k_1 x_1 + k_2 x_2 + \cdots+ k_D x_D \right)
  \right) \, dx_1\,dx_2\ldots dx_D$$

This expression can be rewritten with the dot product as follows:
$$\int_{-N_D}^{N_D}\cdots\int_{-N_2}^{N_2}\int_{N_1}^{N_1} \cos\left( 2\pi k\cdot x\right) \, dx_1\,dx_2\ldots dx_D $$

I've attempted to express the cosine as a sum of two complex exponentials, but that has not led to a nice expression.  Is there a way to integrate this such that the result is a simple expression of the known variables?

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{-N_D}^{N_D}\cdots\int_{-N_2}^{N_2}\int_{-N_1}^{N_1} \cos\left( 2\pi k\cdot x\right) \, dx_1\,dx_2\ldots dx_D
\\[2 em] = Re \bigg [\int_{-N_D}^{N_D}\cdots\int_{-N_2}^{N_2}\int_{-N_1}^{N_1} e^{\left( 2\pi i k\cdot x\right) }\, dx_1\,dx_2\ldots dx_D \bigg]
\\[2em] = Re \bigg [
\frac 1{(2\pi i )^D } \prod_{n=1}^D \frac{2i\sin( 2\pi k_nN_n)}{ k_n } \bigg]$$

$$ = \frac 1{\pi^D}  \prod_{n=1}^D \frac{\sin( 2\pi k_nN_n)}{ k_n } $$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I'd like to note that this is the answer when k_n is not equal to 0. The solution is trivial when it is, but needs to be taken into account.  Thank you for solving the hard part!  :)